# How are function calls within inlined function's body treated?

Tags: c++, inline

Suppose we fave a following header file:

Header1.h

```
#include "Header2.h"

class A
{
public:
    void Function();
}

inline void A::Function() 
{ 
    // Code ...
    OtherFunction(); // Function from Header2.h
    // Code ...
}
```

If a compiler actually **chooses** to inline the `Function` what would happen with the call to `OtherFunction`:

1. If `OtherFunction` definition was available for current translation unit, could it also **possibly** be inlined within the body of `Function`? (Basically are nested inlines available?)
2. If `OtherFunction` definition was not available for current translation unit, will it remain a simple function call, while the code around it gets inlined? (In a situation where compiler chose to inline `Function`)

Comment: It's completely up to the compiler, what's chosen to be inlined.

Comment: You can sort of think of inlining as #includ-ing the function instead of calling it. Roughly. OtherFunction's code will be executed no matter what.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Maybe; that would require LTO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How deep do compilers inline functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463034/how-deep-do-compilers-inline-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the modern compilers actually inlines functions for you when you build your application in release configuration - The effect of `OtherFunction` being declared as inlined/normal will be the same as compiler will decide which is the better option. I certainly know this hapens with MSVC10 and above compilers (Visual Studio). As a matter of fact, inline whatever you want but the compiler ultimately governs what gets inlined.

An example is that if your function calls are chained in a way that the push and pop operations won't make sense after `inline` your functions won't be inlined (even if you declare them to be `inline`d)

If it makes things any easier - see:

[When to use inline function and when not to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932311/when-to-use-inline-function-and-when-not-to-use-it)

[Benefits of inline functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c)

More importantly, [How deep do compilers inline functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463034/how-deep-do-compilers-inline-functions)

has already got a good explanation.

Comment: So even if `OtherFunction` is not marked with `inline` keyword and is defined in separate .cpp file, it still might end up being inlined?

Comment: if you see the links I provided, you can see that `inline` delcarations are merely suggestions to the compiler. Your compiler will ultimately inline what it chooses appropriate. Optimisation is what you are after, more than inlining.

Comment: I feel like a wasn't clear enough with my questions, so I edited them to be more specific. Could you look again please?

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas      Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463034/how-deep-do-compilers-inline-functions)?